# How to hide the check boxes dropdown by clicking outside the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had created a sample check boxes dropdown, I facing an issue in hiding the dropdown by clicking outside the dropdwon. Below is the code

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
$('#checkboxes').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('#checkboxes').style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.category {
  width: 250px;
}

#checkboxes {
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: white;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="category" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
  <option value="">Select cities
  </option>
</select>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <label> 
    <input type="checkbox" /> Bangalore
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox"  /> Hyderabad
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox" /> Delhi
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox" /> Mumbai
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox" /> Chennai
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox"  /> Panaji
  </label>
</div>
```

I want the drop down to get close by clicking outside any where. kindly help me on this i tried the script to make the display style none, but its not working

Comment: See related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

*style* is a property on *HTMLElement*, it is not available on jQuery. You should use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) on jQuery object:

Change

```
$('#checkboxes').style.display = "none";
```

To

```
$('#checkboxes').css("display","none");
```

Though I prefer using `show()/hide()` instead of setting the style property.
You can check the `event.target.nodeName` to `show()/hide()` the element.

Try the following way:

```js
function showCheckboxes() {
  if ($('#checkboxes').is(':visible')) {
    $('#checkboxes').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('#checkboxes').show();
  }
}

                      
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'BODY')
    $('#checkboxes').hide();
});
```

```css
.category {
  width: 250px;
}
#checkboxes {
  width: 250px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: white;
}
#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}
#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="category" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
  <option value="">Select cities
  </option>
</select>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <label > 
    <input type="checkbox" /> Bangalore
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox"  /> Hyderabad
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox" /> Delhi
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox" /> Mumbai
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox" /> Chennai
  </label>
  <label>  
    <input type="checkbox"  /> Panaji
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Something weird is happening with your dropdown. When you click open the dropdown it shows all cities. If you then click next to it, it closes. But if you click again on the dropdown no data is available. and if you then again click out of it and again on it your data will be back.

Comment: @mrdeadsven, you are right, didn't notice that....fixed now....thanks:)

Comment: I checked it works nice now, seems to apply to all the needs that are requested by OP +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try multi Select dropDownList with check Boxes using jQuery plugin as explain here [MultiSelect DropDownList With CheckBoxes In ASP.Net With C# And VB.NET Using jQuery Plugin](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/multiselect-dropdownlist-with-checkboxes-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp-and-vb-net-using-jquery-plugin)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also note that the OP has made no mention or hint that they are using C# or ASP.Net so the link itself seems largely irrelevant to the problem